# Python re.findall output to CSV only works sometimes

Tags: python, regex, export-to-csv

Have some code to find a few matching terms in a string, in my case a log file, I am trying to output the instance to a csv which works, but only sometimes.  If I have too amny variables it seems to break and output a blank csv, otherwise it actually works.

Works:

```
 z = re.findall("(?<=ID\=)\w+", resp)
rec = re.findall("(?<=RECEIVED\=)\w+", resp)

with open('/out.csv','w') as file:
    for x,y in zip(z,rec):
        file.write(x + ',' +y)
        file.write('\n')
```

Gives me a blank csv:

```
i = re.findall("(?<=ID\=)\w+", resp)
rec = re.findall("(?<=RECEIVED\=)\w+", resp)
da = re.findall("(?<=DA\=)\w+", resp)
oa = re.findall("(?<=OA\=)\w+", resp)
st = re.findall("(?<=DELIVERED\=)\w+", resp)
pr = re.findall("(?<=PRICE\=)\w+", resp)
net = re.findall("(?<=NETWORK\=)\w+", resp)
cn = re.findall("(?<=COUNTRY\=)\w+", resp)
gw = re.findall("(?<=GATEWAY\=)\w+", resp)
msg = re.findall("(?<=MSG\=)\w+", resp)

file = (i + ',' + rec + ',' + da + ',' + oa + ',' + st + ',' + pr + ',' + net + ',' + cn + ',' + gw + ',' + msg)
with open('out.csv','w') as file:
    for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,j,k in zip(i,rec,da,oa,st,pr,net,cn,gw,msg):
        file.write(a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ',' + d + ',' + e + ',' + f + ',' + g + ',' + h + ',' + j + ',' + k)
        file.write('\n')
```

Maybe I'm over thinking this or doing way wrong.  Essentially want the output to be these outputs into csv format.  If I'm being dumb feel free to boo me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be much easier to use the pandas included function `pd.to_csv(...)` and store the information in a DataFrame?

> Write DataFrame to a comma-separated values (csv) file. See
>   [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Something like:

```
i = re.findall("(?<=ID\=)\w+", resp)
rec = re.findall("(?<=RECEIVED\=)\w+", resp)
da = re.findall("(?<=DA\=)\w+", resp)
oa = re.findall("(?<=OA\=)\w+", resp)
st = re.findall("(?<=DELIVERED\=)\w+", resp)
pr = re.findall("(?<=PRICE\=)\w+", resp)
net = re.findall("(?<=NETWORK\=)\w+", resp)
cn = re.findall("(?<=COUNTRY\=)\w+", resp)
gw = re.findall("(?<=GATEWAY\=)\w+", resp)
msg = re.findall("(?<=MSG\=)\w+", resp)

indices = ("i", "rec", "da", "oa", "st", "pr", "net", "cn", "gw", "msg")

data = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(i, rec, da, oa, st, pr, net, cn, gw, msg), index=indices)
pd.DataFrame.to_csv(data, "out.csv")
```

---

@JSimonsen:
let's see if this will do the trick?

```
i = ['one', 'two']
rec = ['three', 'four']
da = ['five', 'six']
oa = ['seven', 'eight']

indices = ["col1", "col2"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(i, rec, da, oa), index=indices)
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Because I don't have the data you're using, this is only a simple example I can try, but `re.findall()` returns a list of [strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall). So therefore it should work...

Comment: Hmm That seems like a far better approach than I was doing, but playing around with it at best all it gives me is a literal print of: i
rec
da
oa
st
pr
net
cn
gw
msg In the csv vs the data from the variables themselves

Comment: Yeah this totally works. it seems my data is very specific and break it sometimes.  I just need to be precise in how I define my regular expressions so it doesnt look for other things that match it.  Thanks!